# C++ Generic wrapper class which adds extra processing for some functions

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, generic-programming

I am trying to create a wrapper class for a legacy inheritance hierarchy, which is not strictly polymorphic. And in the wrapper class, I add extra functionality for a few methods, but for many other methods, I just want to call the wrapped class method.

I was wondering if there is a way in which I can write a generic wrapper function in the wrapper class which would allow me to call the wrapped function in a normal way as if there was no wrapper class.
May be I am wrong, but I didn't think overloading operator-> would work because there are some methods of the wrapped class, for which I wanted to do some processing before calling the wrapped class function (though for many others, I don't need to do that). 
 I also had a look at Herb Sutter's wrapper pattern, (again, I might be wrong) but that would need me to have a lambda to access the wrapped function.
 I was wondering whether anyone had any ideas about whether this is achievable?

I have placed the code @ [cpp.sh/2ombu](http://cpp.sh/2ombu)
Here instead of

```
wrapper->operator()([](Derived& x)
{
   x.print();
});
```

or

```
wrapper->operator->()->print();
```

is there someway I can have

```
wrapper->print();
```

Thanks in advance for the answers..

Comment: "but that would need me to have a lambda" - You never *need* a lambda. A lambda is just syntactic sugar for a classical function object. You can always write classical C++98 code to give you the same effect as a lambda (it's just more verbose).

Comment: You should provide the code as text within the question, not via external links!

Comment: Please have a look at discussion to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51519538/1312382), maybe you could be a little bit more precise about what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: @Aconcagua - Sure, will post the code within the question from next time..
And yes, as @Jarod42 said, my problem was the use of pointers.. Once I did the changes he suggested, I can now call the functions to the wrapped class without the need to explicitly use `operator->` . Thanks

Comment: @Joseph And you do add new functions within the wrapper class? Then consider Jarod's `get()` approach, it is dangerous to select one or the other variant of `print` just on the operator being used on the object: `wrapper->print` (getting original print) vs. `wrapper.print()` (getting the changed one). It gets a little more obvious with pointers (`(*wrapper)->print()` vs. `wrapper->print()`), but I still cannot recommend it...

Comment: @Joseph And (unless you still want to use the lambdas for something totally different) you can just drop the `operator()` template, it renders unused now...

Comment: @Aconcagua, true.. I have removed that.. Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you use pointers actually.

Currently, instead of

```
wrapper->operator->()->print();
```

you might write

```
(*wrapper)->print();
```

If you replace unneeded pointers

```
wrap<Derived> *wrapper = new wrap<Derived>(der);
```

by

```
wrap<Derived> wrapper(der);
```

Then, you might replace

```
wrapper->operator->()->print();
```

by

```
wrapper->print();
// or wrapper.operator->()->print(); :)
```

In the same way

```
wrapper->operator()([](Derived& x)
    {
       x.print();
    });
```

would become

```
wrapper(([](Derived& x)
    {
       x.print();
    });
```

Comment: If not replacing: (*wrapper)->print() should work as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Aconcagua: Yes, added.

Comment: Still, we'd always use T's print function. What, if the wrapper shall change print? We'd be able to call both `wrapper.print()` (changed) and `wrapper->print()` (unchanged) then? Don't want to this comment further... (Side note: any of the `->print()` variants don't use `Wrapper`'s `operator()` anyway.)

Comment: @Aconcagua: As written by OP, `wrapper->f(..)` call regular `Derived` function whereas `wrapper.f(..)` would add dedicated stuff (per function: `wrapper` *"redefines"* `prettyPrint` but not `print`) and calling `Derived` function. If it was generic, I would have `wrapper->f()` for extra stuff and `wrapper.get().f()` for regular call.

Comment: `.f()` and `.get().f()` at least makes it pretty clear what one is actually calling, in contrast to either using `.` or `->` only. I understood the question such that this should be transparent (always use .f() or ->f(), using the changed variant, if existing, or the original one otherwise. Normally simply solved by inheritance, but from *"which is not strictly polymorphic"* I concluded that there are non-virtual functions that should be changed as well? Suppose OP should add some details to question...

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly giving you the result you wanted, but still relatively cheap (in sense of code necessary to be written): inheritance:

```
class Wrapped
{
public:
    void f();
    void g();
};

class Wrapper : private Wrapped
{
public:
    // replacing Wrapped's f with own variant:
    void f() { pre(); Wrapped::f(); post(); };
    // pulling Wrapped's g into public  domain again:
    using Wrapped::g;
};
```

So all you have to do is adding the corresponding `using` declarations. If you now ask: *"Why not inherit publicly, then I don't have to?"*, then consider the following:

```
Wrapped* w = new Wrapper();
w->f(); //Wrapped's version of f will be called, as f in given example is not virtual!
```

Maybe you say *"I won't ever use `Wrapped` directly."*. That would work out, but the danger of still using it somewhere and then getting bugs remains immanent with public inheritance...